# Find buildings that overlook 2+ different streets with Overpass Turbo

Tags: overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I am trying to find, with Overpass Turbo, all buildings that overlook two or more different streets.

I tried different codes without much success.
I thought this one would work but not at all...:

```
[out:json][bbox:{{bbox}}][timeout:100];

way["highway"~"trunk|primary|secondary|tertiary|unclassified|residential|footway|pedestrian|living_street"]["footway"!~"sidewalk|crossing"]->.voies1;

foreach .voies1 -> .voie ( 
way(if: t["name"] != voie1.u(t["name"])) ["highway"~"trunk|primary|secondary|tertiary|unclassified|residential|footway"]["footway"!~"sidewalk|crossing"]->.voies2;
nwr(around.voies2:20)(around.voie:20)["building"]->.buildd;
  );

(.buildd;.buildd >;)->.buildd;
.buildd

out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

If anyone has an idea or a lead...

Comment: Overpass API may not be the perfect tool for this use case. Have you looked into PostGIS instead?